# $QR$ decomposition of block matrix

Tags: matrix-decomposition, orthogonal-matrices, block-matrices

Given a square block matrix
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb R^{2d \times 2d},
$$
where $A, B, C, D \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$.

Is there some kind of a *block $QR$ decomposition* like
$$
M = QR = \begin{bmatrix}
Q_1 & Q_2 \\
Q_3 & Q_4
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
E & F \\
0 & G
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for some $E, F, G \in \mathbb R^{d \times d}$?
If yes, can the resulting matrices $E, F, G$ be chosen such that each depends only on a subset of $A, B, C, D$? What is the dependency structure?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never seen such a block decomposition. Good question though. Probably difficult to answer because of the non-unicity of the QR decomposition.

Comment: Not a full answer, but I think this reference might help : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965999000282